# execute functions with millisecond accuracy based on timer

Tags: objective-c, timer, precision

I have an array of floats which represent time values based on when events were triggered over a period of time.

```
0: time stored: 1.68
1: time stored: 2.33
2: time stored: 2.47
3: time stored: 2.57
4: time stored: 2.68
5: time stored: 2.73
6: time stored: 2.83
7: time stored: 2.92
8: time stored: 2.98
9: time stored: 3.05
```

I would now like to start a timer and when the timer hits 1 second 687 milliseconds - the first position in the array - for an event to be triggered/method execution.
and when the timer hits 2 seconds and 337 milliseconds for a second method execution to be triggered right till the last element in the array at 3 seconds and 56 milliseconds for the last event to be triggered.

How can i mimick something like this? i need something with high accuracy

I guess what im essentially asking is how to create a metronome with high precision method calls to play the sound back on time?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> …how to create a metronome with high precision method calls to play the sound back on time?

You would use the audio clock, which has all the accuracy you would typically want (the sample rate for audio playback -- e.g. 44.1kHz) - not an `NSTimer`.

Specifically, you can use a sampler (e.g. AudioUnit) and schedule MIDI events, or you can fill buffers with your (preloaded) click sounds' sample data in your audio streaming callback at the sample positions determined by the tempo.

To maintain 1ms or better, you will need to always base your timing off the audio clock. This is really very easy because your tempo shall dictate an interval of frames.

The tough part (for most people) is getting used to working in realtime contexts and using the audio frameworks, if you have not worked in that domain previously.

Answer (score 2):

To get high precision timing you'd have to jump down a programming level or two and utilise something like the [Core Audio Unit](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/MusicAudio/Conceptual/AudioUnitProgrammingGuide/TheAudioUnit/TheAudioUnit.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003278-CH12-SW1) framework, which offers sample-accurate timing (at 44100kHz, samples should occur around every 0.02ms).

The drawback to this approach is that to get such timing performance, Core Audio Unit programming eschews Objective-C for a C/C++ approach, which is (in my opinion) tougher to code than Objective-C. The way Core Audio Units work is also quite confusing on top of that, especially if you don't have a background in audio DSP.

Staying in Objective-C, you probably know that NSTimers are not an option here. Why not check out the [AVFoundation framework](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/AudioVideo/Conceptual/AVFoundationPG/Articles/00_Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010188)? It can be used for precise media sequencing, and with a bit of creative sideways thinking, and the `AVURLAssetPreferPreciseDurationAndTimingKey` option of  [AVURLAsset](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVURLAsset_Class/Reference/Reference.html), you might be able to achieve what you want without using Core Audio Units.

---

Just to fill out more about `AVFoundation`, you can place instances of `AVAsset` into an `AVMutableComposition` (via `AVMutableCompositionTrack` objects), and then use `AVPlayerItem` objects with an `AVPlayer` instance to control the result. The AVPlayerItem notification `AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTimeNotification` ([docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVPlayerItem_Class/Reference/Reference.html)) can be used to determine when individual assets finish, and the AVPlayer methods `addBoundaryTimeObserverForTimes:queue:usingBlock:` and `addPeriodicTimeObserverForInterval:queue:usingBlock:` can provide notifications at arbitrary times.

With iOS, if your app will be playing audio, you can also get this all to run on the background thread, meaning you can keep time whilst your app is in the background (though a warning, if it does not play audio, Apple might not accept your app using this background mode). Check out [UIBackgroundModes docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/general/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/iPhoneOSKeys.html) for more info.

Answer (score 2):

Look into [`dispatch_after()`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man3/dispatch_after.3.html).  You'd create a target time for it using something like `dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, 1.687000 * NSEC_PER_SEC)`.

---

Update: if you **only** want to play sounds at specific times, rather than do arbitrary work, then you should use an audio API that allows you to schedule playback at specific times.  I'm most familiar with the [Audio Queue API](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/MusicAudio/Reference/AudioQueueReference/Reference/reference.html).  You would create a queue and create 2 or 3 buffers.  (2 if the audio is always the same. 3 if you dynamically load or compute it.)  Then, you'd use `AudioQueueEnqueueBufferWithParameters()` to queue each buffer with a specific start time.  The audio queue will then take care of playing as close as possible to that requested start time.  I doubt you're going to beat the precision of that by manually coding an alternative.  As the queue returns processed buffers to you, you refill it if necessary and queue it at the next time.

I'm sure that [AVFoundation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/AudioVideo/Conceptual/AVFoundationPG/Articles/00_Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010188) must have a similar facility for scheduling playback at specific time, but I'm not familiar with it.

Comment: `dispatch_after()` is a Grand Central Dispatch function. It might be better to look at the Grand Central Dispatch documentation rather than the man page for `dispatch_after()`. https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Performance/Reference/GCD_libdispatch_Ref/Reference/reference.html

Comment: i don't believe this is a highly accurate substitute. here's why: the implementation simply asynchronously adds the block to the queue after the specified time has elapsed. consider it this way: if the queue (or even the system) has a lot of work to do, then it could take quite some time before the block (or work) is actually executed. thus, it's not a substitute for an audio timer. audio callbacks, however, run on realtime high priority threads and have stable time representations. chances are much better using the audio callback, even under high workloads. (cont)

Comment: (cont) furthermore, audio runs on its own time base. that means that the accuracy of this approach is also limited by render block sizes in many cases -- because they use different time bases. people will try to compensate for this inaccuracy by reducing buffer sizes (requiring more resources and often causing more problems, like dropouts). reducing buffer sizes to increase accuracy when not synchronized properly is a brute force solution.

Comment: (cont) combine both of those issues, and the deviation/error can exceed 100ms (and potentially be far greater).

Comment: @Justin, well, you can target the `dispatch_after()` to the high-priority global queue. That gets you at least a somewhat elevated priority. And I'm not sure that using the audio thread helps, because you then have to shunt any meaningful work to another thread, which is likely to introduce similar latency. (You have to shunt it precisely because the audio threads are realtime-ish.)

Comment: @KenThomases elevating the queue's priority still leaves you with the brute force approach and synchronization issues i outlined (at minimum). messing with the priority can also introduce priority inversion. for millisecond or better timing, you should be working in the audio thread - recording the playback position and copying a sample buffer in memory to the output stream is certainly lock free and fast enough for realtime execution in the context of an audio thread. the obvious alternative to copying the sample data to the output stream would be to use a sampler (au).

Comment: I think we're talking at cross-purposes.  The question is not entirely clear as to whether he *just* wants to play sound vs. do arbitrary work.  I have updated my answer with a suggestion to use Audio Queue if he just wants to play audio at specific times.

Comment: @KenThomases the OP's context is very clear at the end: *"I guess what im essentially asking is how to create a metronome with high precision method calls to play the sound back on time?"*. in any case, one would ultimately rely on the running audio clock (or midi event timestamps) for the level of accuracy desired by the OP. audio's a special case… but the problem can be solved by handling the audio stream, or by using timestamped events.

Comment: The suggestions made by several users were to use an audio clock. The audio clock is great for this. A method is available in the openframeworks framework which which makes use of the audio clock and simplifies it to two methods - AudioInput() and AudioOuput() thats for audio recording and audio playback respectively - both being able to execute at 44,100 times per second, great for audio playback and audio input. In my case I wanted a metronome precision method to play my sounds in time.

Comment: (cont)  So if I wanted ticks to be played at a 250 times per minute, thats 44100 execution calls per second * 60 seconds = 2646000 execution calls per minute / 250 ticks = 11025. So that's a tick every 11025 execution calls. To make this work, in the method you have a counter which keeps track of execution calls made so far with simply having counter++. then having a condition that says if(counter % 11025) then play a sound. Every single execution is called so nothing is skipped.

Comment: (cont)  This is how I've utilised the available method without having to dig into the audio clock myself since there's not a lot of documentation on the audio clock in the Core Audio Uni library. Using openframeworks within the project makes this a lot more easier to manage and handle for creative coding. 

It's beautiful :') 

Enough selling, everything worked out great. To sum the conversation you two were having; I most definitely needed a way to execute playback calls at precise centisecond timing. This was achieved with the steps i spoke of.